# Split out strings from a string in c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'd like to split out Australian postcodes from a search string the user supplies.

Australian postcodes are a *4 digit number* in the format `'0000' - '9999'`.

The user should be able to type `"Searchterm 2000 3000"` and the strings `2000` and `3000` should be separated out into a separate variable so that on the backend I can filter the postcode against the search term.

I can do a foreach on the regex match:

```
foreach (var match in Regex.Matches(str, @"<not sure what the regex entry is>"))
```

But then how do I remove those matches from the string so I'm left with the search term? (which can be *multiple words*)

Comment: Question is too broad? Seems pretty specific to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using *regular expressions* (to extract 4-digit numbers) and *Linq* (to organize them):

```
 string source = "Searchterm 2000 3000";

 // "2000 - 3000"
 string result = string.Join(" - ", Regex
   .Matches(source, "[0-9]{4}")
   .OfType<Match>()
   .Select(match => match.Value)
   .Take(2));
```

If you want postcodes's parts being *separated*, just drop `string.Join`:

```
 // parts[0] == 2000; parts[1] == 3000
 string[] parts = Regex
   .Matches(source, "[0-9]{4}")
   .OfType<Match>()
   .Select(match => match.Value)
   .Take(2)
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: The second option is perfect, how do I then remove those postcodes from the original search term?

Answer (score 0):

you Can use string.Split to get an array of strings, for example

```
"Searchterm 2000 3000".Split(' ');
```

will return the following array: ["Searchterm", "2000", "3000"]